# Is ok for implementations of IEnumerator.MoveNext() to include a long running process?

Tags: ienumerator

Are implementations of `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` expected to be relatively quick? Or is it ok if *"moving to the next item"* includes disk IO, web requests, or other potentially long running operations?

For example I'm working on a project which processes documents, and want to abstract the access to the documents as an `IDocumentSource`. Some implementations of `IDocumentSource` may simply pull the documents from the local file system, where other's may download the documents from a webserver to a temp location before opening them. In this case `MoveNext()` would close and delete the previous temp file, and then download and open the next file to process.

Comment: I would be relatively perturbed if it was not "quick"; but even more so with such side-effects.

Comment: Yeah I agree with this. Even if it's not a documented best practice for IEnumerator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no guidelines about the expected performance of `MoveNext()`, unlike the ones that exist for property getters, for example.

You approach looks reasonable. Still, it would be wise to include a note about the behavior in the class/method docs.